# How to write an unit test for 'getCurrentTime()' function?

Tags: unit-testing

I am recently having one getter function which just returns the current Time using certain time format. Since it is returning the current time using some system API, I can't think of a way to write an unit test for this.

Can anyone give suggestion on that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Do you want to test that it returns the correct time? Or that the time is returned in the correct format?

Comment: Hi Daniel,Yes, I would like to test whether it is in the correct time and also in the right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can check if result is not null and if you call it twice, second result is greater than first.

Comment: Nice ones! that would add two for this.

Comment: A possible issue would be if the two system calls happen quickly enough that the time returned doesn't change. I could easily see two calls to System.getCurrentTimeMillis() taking less than a ms. Of course, you could add a call to Thread.sleep() between them, but that feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the System API from your System under test.

A known way to do this is to use Dependency Injection. You inject a class into your time formatter that retrieves the current time.

In your unit tests you insert a Fake CurrentTime api that will return predefined values so you can check the result of your TimeFormatter.
When you're running in production you use the System API.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution is to not use the system time directly, and instead have all your code use a wrapper around System (assuming Java, say) which you can mock out.  This may not be feasible, or easy.

A simpler approach would be to create a second method strictly to do the formatting, which takes the time as a parameter.  You can then test formatting easily and thoroughly.

Then in your original method call the new method passing in the system time (e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis()`) and don't bother writing tests for it.  There's nothing to go wrong that you can do anything about, at that point, so there's really nothing to test.